# Run Python script from any directory using a Poetry virtual environment

Tags: python-poetry

My Python script searches files within the current working directory and uses a Poetry virtual environment to provide necessary Python package dependencies. However, I am running into the following issues:

1. If I directly execute the script, I receive `ModuleNotFoundError` because the virtual environment that contains my Python package dependencies has not been activated.

   ```
   alias script="/path/to/script.py"
   script
   ModuleNotFoundError:
   ```
2. So, I attempt to activate the virtual environment by using `poetry run`. However, this does not work because there does not appear to be an option (as of 6/23/2023) to specify the directory where pyproject.toml is located.

   ```
   alias script=" poetry run /path/to/script.py"
   script
   Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file
   ```
3. So, I attempt to activate the Poetry virtual environment by `cd /path/to` and `poetry run` so that Poetry can find the pyproject.toml file. This activates the environment and runs my script. HOWEVER, since my script searches files in the current working directory, and the current working directory is now the directory containing my pyproject.toml file, I can no longer use my script to search arbitrary directories.
4. It would be possible to directly activate the virtual environment `/<virtual_environment>/bin/activate`. However, Poetry appends a random hash to the end of the virtual environments it creates, so it is necessary to perform some type of discovery to determine the actual name of the virtual environment.

How can I execute my script (1) from an arbitrary directory (i.e., without changing the working directory), and (1) use the Poetry virtual environment?

Comment: Note that Poetry is meant for the development cycle, it is is a development workflow tool. And from my point of view, what you want to do is out of scope for Poetry. What you want to do is a production-time operation, not a development one.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses:

1.) bash command substitution `$(...)` to `cd` to the location of pyproject.toml and runs `poetry env info -p` to extract the full name of the virtual environment WITHOUT changing the current working directory.

2.) Once the full name of the virtual environment is determined, it can be activated by `<virtual_environment>/bin/python3`

3.) After the virtual environment has been activated, the script is called (`/path/to/script.py`). For example, the command `script` can be called from any directory and the script will search for files in that directory while using the Python package dependencies from the correct Poetry virtual environment.

```
alias script="$(cd /path/to/pyproject.toml && poetry env info -p)/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py"
script
WORKS!
```

See also:

- [Ability to specify the directory to run poetry in instead of always using current directory
  #2179](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2179)
- [Option to have the virtual environment's directory name without hash (id) in it #3459](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3459)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe:

```
poetry --directory=/path/to/project run /path/to/script.py
```

The option `--directory` (or `-C`) is documented in [*Commands* -- *Global options*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#global-options).

Comment: `--directory` merely specifies where to find `pyproject.toml`, not the working directory. See: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/7507